# How Can I combine two worksheets merging the data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have information in 2 Excel worksheets that I would like to combine into another worksheet such that for every data item in the first worksheet a copy of all data lines in the second worksheet are added. For example:

```
Sheet One  
     A  
Department 1  
Department 2  
Department 3  

----------------------------------------------

Sheet 2  
    F          G         H  
ItemCode1, ItemDesc1, ItemCost1  
ItemCode2, ItemDesc2, ItemCost2  
ItemCode3, ItemDesc3, ItemCost3  
ItemCode4, ItemDesc4, ItemCost4  
ItemCode5, ItemDesc5, ItemCost5  

----------------------------------------------

Resultant Sheet 3  
      A           F          G          H  
Department 1, ItemCode1, ItemDesc1, ItemCost1  
Department 1, ItemCode2, ItemDesc2, ItemCost2  
Department 1, ItemCode3, ItemDesc3, ItemCost3  
Department 1, ItemCode4, ItemDesc4, ItemCost4  
Department 1, ItemCode5, ItemDesc5, ItemCost5  
Department 2, ItemCode1, ItemDesc1, ItemCost1  
Department 2, ItemCode2, ItemDesc2, ItemCost2  
Department 2, ItemCode3, ItemDesc3, ItemCost3  
Department 2, ItemCode4, ItemDesc4, ItemCost4  
Department 2, ItemCode5, ItemDesc5, ItemCost5  
Department 3, ItemCode1, ItemDesc1, ItemCost1  
Department 3, ItemCode2, ItemDesc2, ItemCost2  
Department 3, ItemCode3, ItemDesc3, ItemCost3  
Department 3, ItemCode4, ItemDesc4, ItemCost4  
Department 3, ItemCode5, ItemDesc5, ItemCost5
```

Can anyone help me out with this? So far, I am attempting to iterate through the data building the new sheet, but I am thinking there may be an easier way to go about it.

Comment: where is the `Key` column to match the data in Sheet1 and Sheet2? You need a `Key` column to know which items are under which department. or is there something in the `ItemCode` that points the `Department`?

Comment: There are no keys - it's just copy/paste sheet2 one time for each row in sheet1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the VBA code for the above, Analyze the Code and trace for better understanding.
Done in meachanical kind of way( Just copy and Paste).
This could have done better, but mine is pretty big code i guess.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim lastrowref As Long

i = 1

Set wkbk = ActiveWorkbook

    Do
        ' to find the range(used to paste values in sheet 3(Column A-Department1
        'and cloumn B( for Values in sheet2)
        lastrowref = lastrow3 + 1

        With wkbk.Sheets(2).Select
        Range("f1:H1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

        Selection.Copy
        End With

        With wkbk.Sheets(3).Select
        Cells(lastrowref, 6).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With

                    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)
' to find the cells where data needs to be pasted
                    lastrow3 = .Range("f1").End(xlDown).Row
                    End With


                    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'to find the number of records in sheet1
                    lastrow = .Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row
                    End With

                    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                    .Cells(i, 1).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    End With

        With wkbk.Sheets(3).Select
        Range(Cells(lastrow3, 1), Cells(lastrowref, 1)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With
' loops till the Number of departments in sheet1
               i = i + 1
    Loop While i <= lastrow


End Sub
```

Comment: your routine does what I need. Thank you. The code errored on the literal "Sheet1" so I removed the quotes.I tried to make the change "Cells(lastrowref, 6).Select", to a 3. However, no matter what I change that value to it causes a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". At the time the error occurs, the results sheet column A is filled with the first department information all the way to the last excel row, 1048576, and one copy of the items is placed starting at column C1.